# How to work on a live WPMS blog when domain is unresolved?

Tags: multisite

How does everyone work on a live blog in WPMS when the domain name still points to a different server/IP? I need to configure the site before the domain Name Server settings are changed to the new host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your computer's [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29), then on a new line, insert the IP address of the *new or old* server from which you'd want to access the site, followed by a space or tab, then type in the domain name (without http://). Here's an example...

```
# This is an example of the hosts file
127.0.0.1  localhost loopback
::1        localhost
23.21.230.21 mydomain.com www.mydomain.com
23.21.230.21 subdomain1.mydomain.com subdomain2.mydomain.com
# None of the following will work as expected. Don't be disappointed!
# 23.21.230.21 mydomain.com www.mydomain.com subdomain1.mydomain.com
# 23.21.230.21 mydomain.com *.mydomain.com
```

Please replace `23.21.230.21` with the actual IP address of the server from which you'd want to access the site. You may also need to **reopen the browsers after every change** in this file.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @brady How is this question off topic? It's a "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that I face" and directy related to "development and management best practices"?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Very much appreciated and exactly what I was after.